# My app not visible in Google play when I search with exact name

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, search-engine

My App is not available in google play when I search with exact name like giving spaces. When I tried entering without spaces the search result will returning my app. 
For Example my App name is "What to do" . If I search Whattodo then only I will get result, If I search with What to do result will not returning for my app.

I check this [link](http://androidforums.com/threads/can-only-see-app-in-google-play-if-searched-with-no-spaces-in-title.871053/) says google compatible with app name with quotes search, But how that user knows to search with quotes?

I given app name in string.xml also correct.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about SEO, not programming

Comment: But basically you picked a horrible name.  3 words that are so generic they're dropped from most searches, and a search concept that would have a huge number of matches.  Getting yourself up in search ranks will take a LOT of time and effort.

Comment: Give it 24 hours after uplishing and then search for it again

Comment: @Gabe Sechan you are saying its SEO concept. Okay then give some suggestion for this how to resolve. I mean is there any way to set meta tags for our app?

Answer (score 0):

@NaveenKumarM : you just givesome time. You will not get the app in search just after publishing. In this week only the app prisma published on  google paly first day if you search for that it will be on the bottom of the page (like after 35 0r 40th ) place. after 4 days it's on the top. it will take time.

Comment: Where I have to give some time? can you elaborate please?

Comment: when you published your app. which date

Comment: Second update published on 2 days before. But this issue will exist on first version also. After 15 days from publish for first release also same issue exist

Comment: is it possible to share the link

Comment: Sorry client is not yet ready to do market on this app, so not able to provide the link without client permission

Comment: didi add all the details in store